# retrieve collect of object in listcollection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a class orderItem it is a parent of Product and service class Im adding product or services in a listcollection. How can I cast service or product for retrieving orderitem?

```
Public MustInherit Class OrderItem
    Private m_enuItemType As TypeOfItem = TypeOfItem.None
    Private m_strUserID As String = ""

    Public Sub New(ByVal enuItemType As TypeOfItem)
        m_enuItemType = enuItemType
    End Sub

    Public Enum TypeOfItem
        None = 0
        Product = 1
        Service = 2
    End Enum

    Public Property ItemType() As TypeOfItem
        Get
            Return m_enuItemType
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As TypeOfItem)
            m_enuItemType = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property UserID() As String
        Get
            Return m_strUserID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_strUserID = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

---

```
Public Class Service
    Inherits OrderItem

    'service Booking Business object 
    Private objServiceBooking As Bo_Dall_Layer.ServiceBooking

    Public Sub New(ByVal enuItemType As TypeOfItem)
        MyBase.New(enuItemType)
    End Sub

    Public Property CartService() As Bo_Dall_Layer.ServiceBooking
        Get
            Return objServiceBooking
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Bo_Dall_Layer.ServiceBooking)
            objServiceBooking = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

---

```
Public Class Product
    Inherits OrderItem

    'product Business object
    Private objProduct As Bo_Dall_Layer.BoProduct

    Public Sub New(ByVal enuItemType As TypeOfItem)
        MyBase.New(enuItemType)
    End Sub

    Public Property Boprd() As Bo_Dall_Layer.BoProduct
        Get
            Return objProduct
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Bo_Dall_Layer.BoProduct)
            objProduct = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

---

```
Public Class CartItem

    Private m_enuItemType As ItemType
    Private m_objOrderItem As OrderItem

    Private Enum ItemType
        Product = 1
        Service = 2
    End Enum

    Public Property Item(ByVal objItem As OrderItem) As OrderItem
        Get
            Return m_objOrderItem
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As OrderItem)
            m_objOrderItem = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

---

```
Public Class UserShoppingCart

    Private m_objArrListOfItems As List(Of OrderItem)

    Public Sub New()
        m_objArrListOfItems = New List(Of OrderItem)(10)
    End Sub

    Public Function AddItem(ByVal objOrderItem As OrderItem) As Boolean
        Try
            ' Validate item to check if it is already in the list
            ' If yes, increment counter, otherwise add new item to the list

            m_objArrListOfItems.Add(objOrderItem)

        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Log error
        End Try
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property ListOfItems() As List(Of OrderItem)
        Get
            Return m_objArrListOfItems
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

I'm using this code for retrieving data in the list collection. I'm getiing this error

### System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'CartProduct' to type 'CartService'. at Cart.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in F:\pic\Eshop\MirraNew\Cart.aspx.vb:line 30

```
Dim arr As New ArrayList
Dim arrService As New ArrayList

Dim objlist As CartProduct
Dim objServiceList As CartService



For Each OrderItem As CartProduct In g_objUserShoppingCart.ListOfItems
    objlist = New CartProduct(Global.OrderItem.TypeOfItem.Product)
    objlist.ProductId = OrderItem.ProductId
    arr.Add(objlist)
Next

'---------------------------------------------------


For Each OrderItem As CartService In g_objUserShoppingCart.ListOfItems
    objServiceList = New CartService(Global.OrderItem.TypeOfItem.Service)
    objServiceList.ServiceName = OrderItem.ServiceName
    arrService.Add(objServiceList)
Next


If Not IsPostBack Then
    ProductCartView.DataSource = arr
    ProductCartView.DataBind()
    ServiceCartView.DataSource = arrService
    ServiceCartView.DataBind()
End If
```

Comment: Why do you post loads of code but leave out the part where the error is raised? (Cart.aspx.vb:line 30)

Comment: please accept my apology because sometime people here want to see more code to understand the program error happening in the last bit code when im trying to retrive  list of product and service object when im adding the object in arraylist to bind to gridview thank you for your help

Comment: @user: so the actual line where the error happens is "in the last bit code when im trying to retrive list of product and service object when im adding the object in arraylist to bind to gridview"? Please show the actual line f.e. `objServiceList = New CartService(Global.OrderItem.TypeOfItem.Service)` and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: erro happen in the first look loop For Each OrderItem As CartProduct In g_objUserShoppingCart.ListOfItems
    objlist = New CartProduct(Global.OrderItem.TypeOfItem.Product)
    objlist.ProductId = OrderItem.ProductId
    arr.Add(objlist)
Next

Comment: What is the exact line??

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is variable name re-use. You're using the same variable name, `OrderItem`, for two different types here. Although in your mind the variable is scoped to that block, by assigning it a type you've fixed it at the method level.

```
For Each OrderItem As CartProduct In g_objUserShoppingCart.ListOfItems
    objlist = New CartProduct(Global.OrderItem.TypeOfItem.Product)
    objlist.ProductId = OrderItem.ProductId
    arr.Add(objlist)
Next

For Each OrderItem As CartService In g_objUserShoppingCart.ListOfItems
    objServiceList = New CartService(Global.OrderItem.TypeOfItem.Service)
    objServiceList.ServiceName = OrderItem.ServiceName
    arrService.Add(objServiceList)
Next
```

There's two solutions, either drop the type declaration (might not work in older versions of VB) or just rename the loop variable.

1)

```
For Each OrderItem In g_objUserShoppingCart.ListOfItems
    objlist = New CartProduct(Global.OrderItem.TypeOfItem.Product)
    objlist.ProductId = OrderItem.ProductId
    arr.Add(objlist)
Next

For Each OrderItem In g_objUserShoppingCart.ListOfItems
    objServiceList = New CartService(Global.OrderItem.TypeOfItem.Service)
    objServiceList.ServiceName = OrderItem.ServiceName
    arrService.Add(objServiceList)
Next
```

2)

```
For Each pOrderItem As CartProduct In g_objUserShoppingCart.ListOfItems
    objlist = New CartProduct(Global.OrderItem.TypeOfItem.Product)
    objlist.ProductId = pOrderItem.ProductId
    arr.Add(objlist)
Next

For Each sOrderItem As CartService In g_objUserShoppingCart.ListOfItems
    objServiceList = New CartService(Global.OrderItem.TypeOfItem.Service)
    objServiceList.ServiceName = sOrderItem.ServiceName
    arrService.Add(objServiceList)
Next
```

A more generic example of your problem is below. This will compile but fail with the same basic error.

```
    Dim Ints As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim Strings As New List(Of String)
    Ints.Add(1)
    Strings.Add("Bob")
    For Each V As Integer In Strings
        Trace.WriteLine(V)
    Next

    For Each V As String In Ints
        Trace.WriteLine(V)
    Next
```

Also, while you're in there, change the definition of the sub-classes, there's no need for a caller to even be aware of the enum:

```
Public Class Product
    Inherits OrderItem

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(Global.OrderItem.TypeOfItem.Product)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Did you try both of the solution that I presented? Also, are you looping in other places in the method?

Comment: i try the first one now im trying the second one

Comment: i was able to solve it i add one more list in shopping cart hence ii  ended two list one for service and one for product it work thank you for your help